# How data is stored in memory beyond 0s and 1s?

Tags: memory, data-storage

I am working as software Engineer. As far as I know the data being stored in memory (Either HARD Disk or RAM) is 0s and 1s.

I am sure beyond 0s and 1s there are different ways data being stored in memory devices based on memory device types.

Please share your ideas about it .

or

Where can I study about the how data stored in memory devices ?

Answer (score 1):

Logically, a bit is the smallest piece of data that can be stored.  A bit is either 0 or 1; nothing else.  It's like asking "what is between these 2 quantum states?"

In electronics 0 or 1 can be distinguished by separate voltage levels, separate directions of magnetization etc.  Some implementations may use multiple levels to store more than one bit in a given space.  But logically 0 or 1 are the only values.